# jQuery .change() event is only fired once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an application that retrieves Project names from a database when the DOM is ready.  Each Project is added to a `<select><option>` in an html `<form>`.  Once the list is populated the user can select a project title, which will request the remaining information from the database specific to that project.

To achieve this I'm using the `$.change()` jQuery method.  Unfortunately, the event is only fired once when the `<select>` element is created and added to the DOM.  Selecting another project from the list does not fire the event, and therefore does not trigger a `$.post()` call.

```
$(function(){
    getProjects();
    var firstLoad = true;

    $("select").change(retrieveProject); // Removed parenthesis based on answers

    // On page load, get project names from the database and add them to a Select form element
    function getProjects() {
        var selectionList;
        $.getJSON("php/getProjects.php", function (data) {
            selectionList = "<form><select>";
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                selectionList += "<option name='prjTitle'>" + data[i].ProjectTitle + "</option>";
            }
            selectionList += "</select></form>";
        }).complete(function() {
           $('#project-selection-menu').append(selectionList).removeClass('hidden');
           firstLoad = false;
        });
    }

    function retrieveProject() {
        if ( firstLoad == true ){
            alert(firstLoad); // This alert fires
            return false;
        } else {
            alert(firstLoad); // This alert doesn't fire
            $.post("php/getProjects.php", function (data) { // This should have been "php/retrieveProject.php"!
                // Do stuff with the returned data
            }).complete(function() {
               console.log("Success.");
            });
        }
    }
)};
```

Comment: I left out the anonymous function and `getProjects();` call to reduce the amount of code shown, but it obviously caused more confusion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're not setting up the event handler properly:

```
$("select").change(retrieveProject);
```

In your code, you were **calling** the "retrieveProject" function, and the return value from that function call was being passed as the "change" handler (and of course having no effect). That's why it appeared that the event was being generated upon page load.

When you're working with a function as a *value*, you don't use `()` after the function reference — it's the reference itself (the function name, in this case) that you want.  That's what needs to be passed to jQuery.

Also — and this is important — make sure that your code is run either in a "ready" or "load" handler, or else that your `<script>` comes *after* the `<select>` element on the page. If the script is in the document head, then it'll run before the DOM is parsed, and it'll have no effect. (Another way to deal with that would be to use an `.on()` delegated form as suggested in another answer.)

---

More: it looks like you're overwriting your `<select>` element when you fetch the content in "getProjects".  Thus, you should definitely use the delegated form:

```
$(document).on("change", "select", retrieveProject);
```

Also, you should be using local variables in "getProjects":

```
function getProjects() {
    var selectionList; // keep this local to the function - implicit globals are risky

    $.getJSON("php/getProjects.php", function (data) {
        selectionList = "<form><select>";
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            selectionList += "<option name='prjTitle'>" + data[i].ProjectTitle + "</option>";
        }
        selectionList += "</select></form>";
    }).complete(function() {
       $('#project-selection-menu').append(selectionList).removeClass('hidden');
       firstLoad = false;
    });
}
```

Comment: I've edited the question to show that I was indeed waiting for the DOM to be ready.  I've removed the parenthesis after my function name, and now neither of the alerts are firing.

Comment: @Roy well "change" events on `<select>` elements definitely work. Do you see any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @Roy ok I think I see the issue - I will add to the answer.

Comment: Success, but could you expand on the "More:" section of your answer?  I'm a geographer not a programmer and this bit is somewhat fuzzy still.

Comment: Ahhhhh I noticed I was sending the post data to the wrong .php file.  I have a separate file for retrieving project-specific data.

Comment: @Roy when you bind an event handler directly to an element (which is what the original code did), then if that element goes away, the handler binding is lost too. When you use the 3-argument `.on()` form, however, the handler binding "lives" at the root of the document. Events "bubble" up through the ancestry chain of elements on the page, so changes to the `<select>` will be seen by that handler. It's an awesomely-useful feature, and it means your handler will still work no matter what happens to the `<select>` element.

Comment: this is an old thread, but this helped me after pulling my hair out for 3 days. +1 Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You need to handle event delegation

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', retrieveProject);
```

Also remove `()` next to the method `retrieveProject`

Answer (score 3):

you can also do this by using following which will work fine.

```
$("select").change(function(){retrieveProject()});
```

or

```
$("select").on('change',function(){retrieveProject()});
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what your looking for?  To run `getProjects` once the page loads just call it in your `$(document).ready()` function.  Also you need to properly setup your `change` handler.  See the fiddle for reference.

```
var firstLoad = true;
getProjects();
$("#selectTest").change(function(){
    retrieveProject();
});

// On page load, get project names from the database and add them to a Select form element
function getProjects() {
    $.getJSON("php/getProjects.php", function (data) {
        selectionList = "<form><select>";
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            selectionList += "<option name='prjTitle'>" + data[i].ProjectTitle + "</option>";
        }
        selectionList += "</select></form>";
    }).complete(function() {
       $('#project-selection-menu').append(selectionList).removeClass('hidden');
       firstLoad = false;
    });
}

function retrieveProject() {
    if ( firstLoad == true ){
        alert(firstLoad); // This alert fires
        return false;
    } else {
        alert(firstLoad); // This alert doesn't fire
        $.post("php/getProjects.php", function (data) {
            // Do stuff with the returned data
        }).complete(function() {
           console.log("Success.");
        });
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/Mf38E/

Comment: See comment on OP -- left out some code to be concise, but it caused additional confusion.  Using the `.change()` callback function as you have it causes neither alert to fire.

Comment: @Roy is your select element being generated dynamically?  I added a `id` to the select.  If your select is not being created dynamically then you can change it to `$("select").change(function(){
    retrieveProject();
});` otherwise go with how Krishna has it set up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(document).bind('change', 'select', function(){
    retrieveProject();
});
```